# Professional jQuery based Combobox control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, controls

Are there any **professional** Combobox controls (dropdown list with autosuggestion) based on the jQuery library?

It should be able to handle **large datasets** and have some **skinning** options. A **multi-column result list** would be great too. I'm working with ASP.NET, but it's a not a problem if I had to write a wrapper for it.

[image]

*I'm already using a third-party control, but I ran into some compatibilty issues between two vendor's controls. Well, I want to get rid of this kind of dependencies.*

Comment: were you ever able to find a better answer to this question ?

Comment: Look at  GeorgeBarker's answer below.

Comment: jQuery's combobox is called 'autocomplete.'  https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best thing I have seen is the [jquery.combobox](http://web.archive.org/web/20130430100104/http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx), but it doesn't really look like something I'd really want to use in my web applications. I think there are some usability issues with this control, but as a user I don't think I'd know to start typing for the dropdownlist to turn into a textbox.

I much prefer the [Combo Dropdown Box](http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/jquery/ddcombobox), but it still has some features that I'd want and it's still in alpha. The only think I don't like about this other than its being alpha... is that once I type in the combobox, the original dropdownlist items disappear. However, maybe there is a setting for this... or maybe it could be added fairly easily.

Those are the only two options that I know of. Good luck in your search. I'd love to hear if you find one or if the second option works out for you.

Comment: I seem to have compatibility issues with jquery.combobox and jQuery 1.4.x ... as with most plugins that have not been maintained for a long time...

Comment: The comment on the first link *'note: at the moment the jquery.combobox behaves as a dropdown list and not a full combbox. it does not currently accept text input.'* kind of defeats the purpose IMO....

Comment: dead link at sanchezsalvador.com

Answer (score 53):

Here's one that looks very promising.  It's a true combo - you see what you type.  Has a cool feature I haven't seen elsewhere: paging results.

[FlexBox](http://www.codeplex.com/flexbox)

Comment: I will second the FlexBox recommendation. It is has a very, umm, flexible styling and UI options.

Comment: New version (0.9.3) just released.  FlexBox now supports client-side JSON filtering.

Comment: imo FlexBox is for some cases overkill.

Comment: Appears to load all the data (json) at once so may not be appropriate if data source has lots of records

Comment: If I already select one value, then click arrow it only show the selected value, not all value.

Answer (score 25):

Anyone looking for a jquery "combo box" seems to be directed to this question. My post is for people coming to this page to find a "traditional" combo box, rather than an answer to the original question. The above solutions all focus on using the input as a means to filtering and autocompleting to an existing select value. (great for large datasets)

If you're looking for the traditional combo box, which is simply "Type something or select from these pre-defined values" (no we won't hide the ones that don't match while you're typing), all you may need to do is

```
<select id="combo4" style="width: 200px;"
            onchange="$('input#text4').val($(this).val());">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
<input id="text4"
       style="margin-left: -203px; width: 180px; height: 1.2em; border: 0;" />
```

See
http://bit.wisestamp.com/uncategorized/htmljquery-editable-combo-2/

Should be easy to wrap this into a plugin that converts an existing select tag, though I haven't seen that done yet.

P.S.: The main problem I see with "jQuery Editable Combobox" is that it remains a select list, and it is not obvious at all that you can just start typing something new.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X657V/

Answer (score 15):

A new fork of the sexy-combo project is now out which looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/ufd/

Comment: I like that it turns a select into a combobox.

Comment: After reviewing every suggestion on the page, I settled for this one. Fast, simple, provides just the basic functionality I wanted, and worked on an existing select input

Comment: Can also work with Jquery UI Themeroller

Comment: This one was the biz for me.  Works seamlessly on IE7 and IE8, which was a requirement.  Infix (mid-word) searching, scroll bars for longer lists, and plays nicely with other components.

Comment: This is by far the easiest to integrate if your existing code uses an old html dropdown. I used this one.

Answer (score 14):

For large datasets, how about [JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete), which is basically the "official" version of Jorn Zaeferrer's [Autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)?

I also wrote a straight [JQuery combobox](http://jonathan.tang.name/code/jquery_combobox) plugin that's gotten pretty good feedback from its users.  It's explicitly *not* meant for large datasets though; I figure that if you want something that prunes the list based on what the user types, you're better off with Jorn's autocompletion plugin.

Comment: Jorn Zaeferrer's Autocomplete plugin is simple and awesome

Answer (score 10):

Another nice plugin is [Sexy Combo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SexyCombo)

Comment: This project has stopped active development.

Comment: See the UFD fork of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control/2629205#2629205

Answer (score 7):

This is also promising:

[JQuery Drop-Down Combo Box](http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/jquery/ddcombobox) on simpletutorials.com

Comment: Looks pretty nice, but doesn't support having a different name and value like you can with select <options>

Comment: Also doesn't support two combo boxes on one page.

Answer (score 7):

An official jQuery UI ComboBox/Autocomplete component is in the making... (previously in beta for jQuery UI 1.5.x), see [jQuery UI Wiki](http://jqueryui.pbwiki.com/SelectComboboxAutocomplete)

UPDATE:

Autocomplete functionality is now a core feature of jQuery UI, [see docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: This is now live with jQuery 1.8. I'm using it quite successfully, it's been a well designed widget.

Comment: Are you guys experiencing the post effect?  When I click the arrow to toggle the list, my page is posted and I get a page refresh...

Comment: a combobox is not the same as autocomplete

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need multi-column, [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is another good choice. MIT Licensed

Comment: +1 for chosen. Looks great and we didn't have to make any changes to existing dropdowns with data coming from an ObjectDatasource. It just works!

Answer (score 3):

I found this other one: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jec/

Also seems like a good option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for the same.
The one I liked most till now is this one for ExtJs - except I havent tested it with large Lists:
www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html

Here is another really(!) fast one:
http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/

For example the SexyCombo works quite fantastic but is way to slow for
longer lists.
The SexyCombo folk UFD is a lot faster, but initialization time is still quite slow for really huge lists.
Besides I get sometimes some little! "flashing".
But I guess there will be some updates in the near future.

Comment: ExtJs works also very well with large (or huge) lists because it supports paging and you can either query the values locally or decide to send the query back to the server and supply another chunk of results. The problem with ExtJs is it's steep learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

Sexy-Combo has been deprecated. Further development exists in the Unobtrusive Fast-Filter Dropdown project. Looks promising, as i have similar requirements.

https://code.google.com/p/ufd/

Comment: Although nice, it seems it doesn't work with jquery > 1.6. Looking for other options.

Answer (score 3):

I like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), it's feature-rich and nice and active.  Particularly like the [diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) search feature.

Comment: Word. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try http://jqueryajax.codeplex.com/. It is a collection of ASP.NET controls that contains multicolumn drop down as well.

Answer (score 2):

Activewidgets has a very nice looking one.  No idea how well it performs on large datasets.
http://www.activewidgets.com/ui.combo/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I ended up making my own.

It has a template system built in, so you can make the results look like anything you want.
Works on all major browsers and accepts arrays & json objects.
http://code.google.com/p/custom-combobox/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really cool one: http://www.xnodesystems.com/ The Dynamic List Field not only has the autocomplete capability, but also is able to do validation.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox and the problems faced were:

- Cross browser rendering
- Inability to submit custom value

As a result I've tweaked it a bit and it worked fine for me in ASP.NET MVC. My version of CSS and widget script can be found here http://saplin.blogspot.com/2011/12/html-combobox-control-and-aspnet-mvc.html

Sample on binding MVC model to custom value is also there.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm

Very nice with many features including localization.

Comment: Just working with div also heavy to load

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommending Twitter Typeahead:

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 0):

all what you need 
http://jquerycomboboxtmpl.codeplex.com/

drop-down on templates

Comment: Please add some explanation at least for the solution you are suggesting and why it fits the criteria from the question.