# jquery search / combobox combination?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, combobox

I wish the following:

- a text input
- a "go" button

You type in the text input.

If you hit enter or the "go" button, it puts (remote) search results in a drop-down for you to select (each item has an image and some text).

If you start typing again, it clears back to original state (i.e. no drop-down).

I'd like it to be jquery or a jquery plugin.

It's almost like the jquery auto-complete drop-down, but that doesn't wait for enter or a "Go" button.

It's sort of like a combobox, but I don't have the items beforehand.

I've been wandering around looking at jquery plugins, jquery ui, [jquery combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control), etc.  I'm confused whether this exists or I have to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [Droplist Filter](http://nihilex.com/droplist-filter)? I haven't messed with it so I don't know if it will work with server side data =(

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  It looks like it cannot query a remote server.