# Combo control like Windows Vista

Tags: html

I want to make a combo control that looks very classic and very sexy, as Vista's does.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- [Sexy Combo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SexyCombo)

2- [FlexBox](http://www.codeplex.com/flexbox)

3- [Combo DropDown Box](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DDComboBox)

4- [Jquery.combo](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx)

5- [Jquery drop down combo box tutorial](http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/jquery/ddcombobox)

6- [ActiveWidget Combo Box](http://www.activewidgets.com/ui.combo/)

7- [.... may be a duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control)

Comment: Hi michel thanks for reply, am not sure my post is duplicate, but b4 submit , i checked this forum, also am not sure which keyword is my question, i tried like clasic combo, sexy combo keywords, but am not find much more help full thread result, thanks for your inform , the above mentioned really fine, can u tell me , what is the keyword suitable for my question , i google ya..

Comment: you should learn about jquery http://jquery.com ... in this case: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=dropdown+combobox+jquery