# jQuery combobox suggestion

Tags: jquery, combobox

Can someone suggest me some jQuery combobox for rich internet application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: find anything here ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQueryUI has an [autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) that can be used as a combobox.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.combobox](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx) seems to be the standard and most-used.

Although there is a similar question here with heaps of useful answers: [Professional jQuery based Combobox control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control)

**Update:**
Direct link to a demo: [clicky](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxexamplebasic.aspx)