# Looking for a filtered dropdown list for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have some DropDownList controls where the list is very large, so I would like to have a means for the user to filter the list, either based on other fields, e.g. region, or on the first letters typed in a textbox.  How can I achieve this in ASP.NET?  Is the an open source control out there that will help me?

Comment: Please select an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the Cascading Drop Down, or the List Search Extender within the Ajax Control Toolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ListSearch/ListSearch.aspx

Comment: The List Search Extender looks a very close fit, thanks.

Comment: @ProfK, I hope the List Search Extender works out for you.  Let me know if you have questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think in terms of a filtered control - think in terms of filtering the data.

Consider using `SqlDataSource` or one of the other data source controls as the source for your dropdown. You can then use other controls for filtering.

Comment: I am looking at filtering the data, but I would like use the control to determine how its data is filetered.

Answer (score 1):

I use the JQueryUI autocomplete widget along with an ajax call to a local web service. It works quite well.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some client script combo boxes like the one's in the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control)