# Any jQuery plugin that could replace html select tag?

Tags: jquery, html, select

It's nothing new - select tag looks damn ugly.

Is there nice jQuery plugin out there that could replace it with ease?

Comment: @krike accepted just because You asked. it's not time that decides if question should be resolved but quality of given answers.

Comment: You are completely correct. but since you didn't answer on my last comment I concluded you did not need help anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this could be usefull to you -> http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/2009/05/jquery-plugin-stylish-select-unobstrusive-select-box-replacement/

Comment: This one looks quite good. I just got bad feeling that it does not automatically sync selected option with invisible `select` tag. Is that so?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What do you mean with sync selected option with invisible select tag? Your question was about styling it, right?

Answer (score 1):

[ASM Select](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-asmselect/) is especially nice if you want to improve the appearance and user experience of `select`s with multiple enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SelectBoxIt](http://www.selectboxit.com).  SelectBoxIt can use both **jQuery ThemeRoller** and **jQueryUI show/hide effects**.  It currently does not have support for the multiple HTML property though.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control) is similar. You could try [jquery.combobox](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx).