# Idea needed for dropdown implementation

Tags: menu, drop-down-menu

I have to implement the following dropdown box. The first item in the list can't selected and the data will be populated dynamically.

[image: Dropdown to be implemented]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for an [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Choose Types">
    <option>All Types</option>
    <option>CAR</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: it works. Can you please tell me how to resize the select popup shown in the above picture? thanks.

Comment: Without breaking it off it to a floating div or some kind of popup mechanism, you're not going to be able to. stock controls use the original width as the width of the drop-down. You can take a look at [ComboBox alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control) though.