# Multi-column Select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, combobox

Im looking for a multi-column select box that is searchable.

I have found Flexbox (http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox) which does almost everything I need except it limits searching only to the {name} column. I'm needing something that will search over all columns shown.

Im looking for something as powerful as the MS Access dropdown boxes if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would also suggest marking some answers on previous questions, it will most likely help you get more answers/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a (rather crude) custom combo box using div's and a bit of javascript. While it isn't the most elegant it works for my purposes.

Hopefully someone is working on something similar to this but for now this is the only solution I was able to find.

Comment: Hello @AverageMarcus, could please share the code. I'm looking for that too. TIA

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you're looking for...

[Presenting SooperFish: jQuery plugin for Multi-Column Dropdown Menus](http://www.sooperthemes.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-sooperfish-dropdown-menus)

Comment: No, its a combo box im looking for (form object), not a dropdown menu.

Comment: I found this question which is similar to yours and unfortunately it looks to have the same issue you're having. the current options available are jquerys autocomplete or their combo box and flexbox, which you're currently using.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195270/professional-jquery-based-combobox-control